# Error MSB6006: "midl.exe" exited with code 2026

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to build a VC++ project in Visual Studio 2013. While building I get the error message as follows:

```
Error   3   error MSB6006: "midl.exe" exited with code 2026. C:\somePath\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   1178    5   myProject
```

The weird thing is, If I try to build in debug mode, I don't get the error message. It is only when I try to build in Release mode that I get this strange error. All Solutions via StackOverflow and other workarounds for me have failed to diagnose it and hence I am posting it finally. Any clue what would be wrong ?

Comment: It means "cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting".  We can't see the syntax errors.  Look in the Output window.

Comment: there are no syntax errors. I did check the Microsoft error guide for this error code 2026 but it totally is misleading, at least for my case. The same code is being built for the Debug and release versions so I fail to understand why the debug version does not have a problem.

Comment: Here is the only error from the output window which is probably what you are referring to:
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.

Answer (score 0):

MIDL2026 error message is generated during MIDL compilation.

MIDL2026 error means that midl attempted but it cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation.
The MIDL compiler automatically tries to recover from syntax errors by adding or removing syntactic elements. This message indicates that despite these attempts to recover, the compiler detected too many errors. Correct the specified error(s) and recompile.

First, you can try to reset Visual Studio settings:
Click Tools in the menu->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings, when you load the Visual Studio again, you can choice the C++ environment.

Second, you can use /SafeMode (devenv.exe) to prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts.
Also, you can use /ResetSkipPkgs (devenv.exe) to clearing the tag re-enables the loading of the VSPackage.

I hope my suggestions can help you to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to fix your problem by removing the /mktyplib203 switch from your MIDL settings.

Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->MIDL->General->MkTypLib Compatible: Yes (/mktyplib203)

Comment: I've already tried that and it does not work at all. Definitely not a solution to even try to my knowledge since it will mess up the project build settings.